# Retrieving more than 1000 contacts using ngCordova in AngularJS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app in Ionic framework which displays all contacts from device to end User and gives option for selection of contacts.
I am using ngCordova's $cordovaContacts module for fetching contacts.

This is the service code which fetches contacts from the device.

```
angular.module('starter.services').factory('ContactManager', function($cordovaContacts, $ionicLoading){
  return {
    getContacts: function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({ template: "<div class='ion-ios7-reloading'></div>"});
      var options = {};
      options.filter = "";
      options.multiple = true;
      options.fields = ['displayName', 'name', 'phoneNumbers', 'emails'];
      //get the phone contacts
      return $cordovaContacts.find(options);
    }
  }
});
```

Below is controller code which assigns contacts to $scope.contacts variable

```
angular.module('starter.ctrls').controller('ShareCtrl', function($scope, ContactManager, $stateParams) {

  $scope.contacts = [];

  ContactManager.getContacts().then(function(_result){
    alert("CONTACTS FETCHED: Now rendering in Template");
    $scope.contacts = _result;
   }, function(_error){
    alert("Error: " + _error);
  });

});
```

It works fine for 100-400 contacts.
But for devices with around 1000 contacts, it takes lots of time to fetch contacts from plugin(CONTACTS FETCHED alert in controller is shown after 2-3 minutes). After fetching contacts from plugin it again takes 2-3 minutes to render in UI(using ng-repeat) and most of the times app hangs.

I also searched for pagination while fetching contacts but could not find any option to fetch contacts page wise in ngCordova documentation.
As of now I am testing on android and the app hangs in case of contacts count is around 1000.
How can I improve its performance?
I am a newbie to angular and ionic.

Comment: Have you found a way to optimize this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Would recommend instead of loading 100-400 contacts in one shot display 100 contacts as the user scrolling down you can load the next 100 contacts. To achieve this you can use this plugin .
http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

If they are in the read only contacts you can use "BindOnce" Plugin which will improve the binding the scope once and keeps your browser light. https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, using BindOnce  will save time of rendering, but I need two way binding for selection of contacts by User.
Also contacts from plugin are loading slowly.

Comment: 1.How fast your server is your server responding to your request. You can check that in the developer tools-->Network Tab. Have you tried the ng-infinite-scroll and load the data asynchronously in bits.

Comment: Server is not in a question here. Data is in the device itself. I am fetching contacts from mobile device and app is in mobile.